# How to convert a systemd service to docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, systemd

I have an existing custom service at `/lib/systemd/system/custom.service` with:

```
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=customuser
ExecStart=/opt/customservice /opt/custom.config

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With:

```
systemctl enable custom.service
systemctl start custom.service
```

How can I convert this service to a docker container, keeping in in foreground and always up and running?

I started with a `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:20
COPY /custom.service /opt/app/
COPY /custom.config /opt/app/

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/custom.service", "/opt/custom.config" ]
```

But how can I now achieve the same configuration as I had in the native `systemd` service?

Comment: I think that depends a lot on what the service actually is, how it takes its configuration, whether it normally daemonizes itself, and so on.  You definitely would not include the systemd service file in the container; instead you'd set the main container command to actually run the process (I'd recommend doing it in `CMD` rather than `ENTRYPOINT` for being easier to debug and to adapt to some common Dockerfile patterns).

Comment: It's a simple service that offers a socket port, if that helps. How would I have to start it and keep it alive with `CMD` instead?

Comment: Looking at the systemd unit file, is the command to run the process just `/opt/customservice /opt/custom.config`?  Make that be the `CMD`.

Comment: It's just exactly as in the question